# Я выхожу из приложения, но у меня есть в диспетчере. Как закрыть его и там?

Tags: java, android

Я выхожу из приложения так, но у меня оно висит и в диспетчере. Как закрыть его и там?

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(R.string.exit)
                .setMessage(R.string.exit_yes)
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        Main2Activity.super.onBackPressed();
                    }
                }).create().show();
    }
```

Comment: А зачем его там закрывать? Это одна из самых ненавидимых особенностей приложений. Если пользователю оно ненужно в списке последних, он сам его уберет. А если нужно, но его не будет, то в адрес разработчика будут лететь лучи проклятий и поноса.

Comment: Эникейщик, раз человек спрашивает как закрыть приложение, то его интересует, как это не странно ... как закрыть приложение. А так как он способен программировать под андроид, то ему, более чем очевидно, хватило ума подумать и о второстепенных вещах.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код из диалога работает по принципу, как-будто бы вы нажали кнопку назад, таким образом сворачивая его. Чтобы выйти из приложения можно использовать такой код:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startActivity(intent);
```

он имитирует нажатие на кнопку "Домой" но приложение все-равно будет работать и будет свернуто в трее. Чтобы убить приложение окончательно можно использовать такой способ:

```
int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
```

эта команда полностью "убьет" процесс приложения закрыв его.

### UPDATE

нашел еще один способ. В манифесте нужно добавить:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.ExitActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
    android:autoRemoveFromRecents="true"/>
```

и дальше создаем класс помощник:

```
public class ExitActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
        {
            finishAndRemoveTask();
        }
        else
        {
            finish();
        }
    }

    public static void exitApplication(Context context)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ExitActivity.class);

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);

        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

и там где нужно закрываем приложение:

```
ExitActivity.exitApplication(context);
```

[Ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22166282/close-application-and-remove-from-recent-apps) на первоисточник.

Comment: к сожалению также не работает ( выходит но остается в диспетчере  ) я сверху добавил правку как я написал !

Comment: @Yacow, обновил ответ, посмотрите может так получится закрыть

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать `finishAndRemoveTask()` в MainActivity.
`finishAndRemoveTask()` - завершает все activity в task и удаляет сам task.
Данная функция доступна начиная с API 21.

Answer (score 0):

Я добавил это в манифест  android:excludeFromRecents="true" в Activity с которой буду в дальнейшем выходить и это работает . Осталось понять что это и как оно работает ) + этого всего в том ,что работает на разных api